# Bluetooth won't work after running powertop -c

Tags: bluetooth, adapter, powertop

I'm on Manjaro Linux.
I ran `powertop -c`, and after the calibration process, my bluetooth stoped working.

Here are the ouputs of somme commands I ran:

```
$ lsmod | grep bluetooth
bluetooth             626688  7 bnep
ecdh_generic           24576  1 bluetooth
rfkill                 28672  8 bluetooth,dell_laptop,dell_rbtn,cfg80211
crc16                  16384  2 bluetooth,ext4

$ rfkill list all
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0c45:6a05 Microdia 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

However, I have no idea of how to fix it.